# Java Scanner Input not allowing input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to add entries to an ArrayList in Java and I had it working, but now it isn't. Here is the code

```
import java.util.*;

public class SalesPerson 
{  
// define an array of allowable sales person to be three
static String[] salesPerson = new String[3]; 

/**
 * Calculates the total annual compensation for a salesperson by 
 * multiplying annual sales by commission rate and then adding the salary
 */
public static void compensation()
{
    try {
        String[] salesperson = new String[3];
        // use scanner class to read input from the user
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        // List to add entries to an array list
         ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        // do..while loop to add salespersons 
        do {
            System.out.println("Want to compare additional " //GLD-changed verbiage here
                    + "salespeople? (y/n)"); //GLD-changed verbiage here
            if (input.next().startsWith("y")) {
                System.out.println("Enter the salesperson's name:"); 
                addSalesPerson(list).add(input.next());
                System.out.println("Enter annual amount for salesperson");
                addSalesPerson(list).add(input.next());
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } 
        while (true); 
        // System.out.println(addSalesPerson(list).get(1));
        // check to see if only two sales persons have been entered
        if (addSalesPerson(list).size() < 2 || addSalesPerson(list).size() > 4) {
            throw new Exception("You may only enter two sales persons.");
        }

        Object[] arr;
        arr = addSalesPerson(list).toArray(new String[addSalesPerson(list).size()]);

        // loop through the length of the array
        for (Object arr1 : arr) {
            salesperson = (String[]) arr;
        }

        // for this, we will compare two sales people only
        float sale2 = Float.parseFloat(salesperson[1]);
        float sale4 = Float.parseFloat(salesperson[3]);

        // subtract based on which variable is greater to ensure no negative values
        float difference = sale2 > sale4 ? sale2 - sale4 : sale4 - sale2;
        // print out the difference
        System.out.printf("To match the other sales person's amount " 
                + "you will need to get $%.2f more\n\n", difference);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle any exception by displaying an error message
        System.out.println("Something went wrong while processing your " 
                + "input. Please be sure you only entered numeric values" 
                + " and or the correct amount of salespersons.");
    } 
}

/**
 * Adds sales people to an array list
 * @param salesperson
 * @return ArrayList
 */
static public ArrayList addSalesPerson(ArrayList<String> salesperson)
{ 
    for (int i=0; i<salesPerson.length; i++) {
         if (salesperson.get(i).equals("")) {
             break;
         }

         salesperson.add(salesperson.get(i));
    }

       return salesperson;
    }
}
```

And then I am calling these static methods in two other files

```
 public class Getters 
 {
     public static void handleSalesPersonCompensation() 
     {
        SalesPerson.compensation();
     }
 }

 public class ComparisonWk5 
 {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Getters.handleSalesPersonCompensation();
    } 
}
```

The output of these should be 
Want to compare additional salespeople? (y/n)
y
Enter the saleperson's name: My Name
Enter the annual amount for salesperson: 200000
Want to compare an additional salespeople? (y/n)
y
Enter the saleperson's name: My Name 2
Enter the annual amount for salesperson: 100000

To match the other person's amount, you will need to get $100000 more

But the output is:
Want to compare additional salespeople? (y/n)
y
Enter the salesperson's name:
Something went wrong while processing your input. Please be sure you only entered numeric values and or the correct amount of salespersons.

Everytime after I type "y", it shows the salesperson's name input but also displays the exception right after without having the ability to enter a name.

Any help would be appreciated

The stack trace is this:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at SalesPerson.addSalesPerson(SalesPerson.java:96)
    at SalesPerson.compensation(SalesPerson.java:48)
    at Getters.handleSalesPersonCompensation(Getters.java:61)
    at ComparisonWk5.main(ComparisonWk5.java:31)
```

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `e.printStackTrace()` to the exception catching and running, that way we can know where the problem occurred and why. Usually catching all Exceptions like that isn't recommended, I believe. You should certainly post the stacktrace so you know what went wrong.

Comment: [java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653), java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429), SalesPerson.addSalesPerson(SalesPerson.java:96), SalesPerson.compensation(SalesPerson.java:48), Getters.handleSalesPersonCompensation(Getters.java:61), ComparisonWk5.main(ComparisonWk5.java:31)]

That's the stack trace.

Comment: Uh, I recommend editing the post and putting it in there, as code. It's almost impossible to read here.

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace!

Comment: So you didn't copy the top of the stack trace, which gives the exact error, but it looks like you passed a bad error. Which line of your coed is line 96? (Look in your IDE, it should be there)

Comment: Remember that in Java indices start with 0, so index 3 is actually the fourth index.

Comment: System.out.print(e.printStackTrace());

This is causing an error. it won't let me use it..

Comment: Use just `e.printStackTrace()` ...

Comment: This `Float.parseFloat(salesperson[3]);` if there are only 3 entries in that array. Btw your `addSalesPerson` method doubles the amount of entries (if there are no empty strings in there).

Comment: You're trying to access the index `0` of an empty list. The problem is the whole `addSalesPerson` method, for example because got confused with array `salesPerson` and list `salesperson` (which are different variables) and because it doubles the first 3 entries of your list.

Comment: How does it double the first three entries? (Sorry, I am new to Java)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74021/discussion-between-user2101411-and-tom).

Comment: This line causes that: `salesperson.add(salesperson.get(i));`. It takes the item on index `i` and adds it to the end of the same list. Therefore this list contains that particular item twice. And it only "copies" the first three items, because the used `for` loop uses the length of  `salesPerson`, which is three.